# object UTF8String is not a member of package

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

How to solve this issue when executing a Maven program from IntellijIdea (with SBT Incremental compiler):

> Error:(27, 38) object UTF8String is not a member of package
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types import
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.{fromString => toUTF8}
>                                        ^
>
> Error:(37, 14) not found: value toUTF8
>         assert(toUTF8(s).toString() === s)
>                ^

The project has been built successfully.

Comment: Did you define a special [scope](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) for [spark-unsafe_2.xx](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|spark-unsafe) that excludes it (from tests, I assume, due to `assert`)?

Comment: @Gerold Broser: What do you mean? I am new to maven and scala.

Comment: Did you follow the first link mentioned above? Can you supply the `pom.xml` of your project?